# Count lines in file, float numbers in chosen lines, add them and compute average

Tags: python

> Write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and
>   reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:
>
> `X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475`
>
> Count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of
>   the lines and compute the average of those values and produce an
>   output as shown below. Do not use the `sum()` function or a variable
>   named `sum` in your solution.
>
> You can download the sample data at
>   http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt
>   When you are testing below enter `mbox-short.txt` as the file name.

That's my code, which is not working. If you know how to fix it, please explain (as simple as possible):

```
# Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
total = 0
for line in fh:
    if not float(line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:")) : continue
    count = count + 1
    float(total) = float(total) + float(line)
float(average = total/count)
print "Average spam confidence: ", average
```

Correct answer should be: `Average spam confidence: 0.750718518519`

Comment: you need to extract the float string from the rest of the line before trying to either convert it or do arithmetic on it. "line" still contains the entire line.

Comment: The first thing for you to do is to remove the syntax errors from your code. Do that before you try to fix the logic. You should have done that before asking your question here: do as much as you can first. You will learn better that way.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything in your code to actually extract the float value from the line. Simply casting the `line` as a float and trying to add it to total wont work, because `line` is referring to the entire line from the file. An easy way to extract the float value would be to split the line by the `:` and then take everything after it. That can be done like this: `floatnum = line.split(':')[1]` The `[1]` means that it will take everything after the delimiter that we used to split the line, which in this case was `:`.

You have some other errors in your code, so if you just want to take how I extracted the float and apply that to the method you're using and adjust your code accordingly then that would be a good idea.

Here's a working example for you though that will get done what you need:

```
fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
file = open(fname)

counter = 0
total = 0.0

for line in file:
    if 'X-DSPAM-Confidence:' in line:    # checks to see if line pertains to you
        counter += 1                     # if so, increment counter
        floatnum = line.split(':')[1]    # splits line at ':' and takes everything after it
        total += float(floatnum)         # ... and adjust total

average = total/counter                  # gets average

print 'Average spam confidence: ' + str(average)
```

I used this file as input, which contains:

```
hello world
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
hello world
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8400
hello world
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.9475
hello world
```

Result:
`Average spam confidence: 0.878333333333`

Comment: The line `floatnum.lstrip().strip('\n')` doesn't do anything, but it doesn't affect your code because `float` ignores leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @YolantaJenkins Glad this solved your problem. If this was a solution consider marking it at the answer to help others.

Answer (score -1):

fname =input('Enter file name: ')
file = open(fname)

count = 0
total = 0.0

for line in file:
    if 'X-DSPAM-Confidence:' in line:
        count = count +1
        floatnum = line.split(':')[1]
        total= total + float(floatnum)
average = total/count
print ('Average spam confidence: ' + str(average))